# (547) - Conflito de Foreign Key - Como resolver?

Tags: sql-server, .net, stored-procedures

Conflito com uma chave estrangeira existente na tabela GAM_USER - Tentando add um user novo, mas já existe um usuário na mesma tabela que possui o mesmo cpf, sendo que o anterior eu não posso exclu[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kTjL.png)ir. Tenho que manter o novo user. Algúem sabe como posso resolver este issue?

Banco SQL server 2012
aplicação web em .NET
servidor de aplicação IIS
Crystal Report
.Net FW[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR8Nh.png)

Comment: Um user com o mesmo cpf ... não seria o caso de update no já existente ?

Answer (score -3):

Se o usuário já existe, o correto seria alterar esse registro, e não tentar adicionar o mesmo registro novamente.